# How can I pass an argument to a directive function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My HTML is

```
<ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions-list"><li 
        ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions track by $index" 
        class="suggestion-item" 
        ng-click="toggleSkill(suggestion, 'here')" 
        ng-class="{active : selectedIndex === $index}"
    ><span class="small clr-secondary">{{suggestion}} - {{$index}}</span></li></ul>
```

And in the directive, I have:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  scope.toggleSkill = function(item, index) {
    debugger
    SkillsService.searchResults = []

    if (scope.selectedTags.indexOf(scope.suggestions[index]) === -1) {
      scope.selectedTags.push(scope.suggestions[index])
      scope.searchText = ""
```

For some reason, the `index` in the function comes in as `undefined`. Why would that be?

Comment: really odd... does suggestion is passed correctly? if you try a `console.log(arguments);` inside your function, can you see the parameter 'here' somewhere?

Comment: `suggestion` passes properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code works fine when I copy pasted it inside a template/directive. Here's a slightly more stripped down version for ease of read. Check if this works.

```
<!--inside ur template-->
<p class="text" ng-click="zoo('param1', 'param2')">click me</p>

// inside ur directive
$scope.zoo = function (x, y) {
     console.log('my params ', x, y);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
ng-click="toggleSkill(suggestion, $index)"
```

Comment: Is not necesary use scope.suggestions[index]
because you already has the suggestion instance in the parameter.

If the item not exist in scope.selectedTags then
scope.selectedTags.push(item)

 you understand Me? (sorry by my english)